# How to change cart subtotal price in order summary block magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

How can I do that?

this is my code.

```
$quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
$grand_total = $quote->getGrandTotal();
$new_grand_total = $grand_total + $fee;

$quote->setGrandTotal($new_grand_total);
$quote->setBaseGrandTotal($new_grand_total); 
$quote->collectTotals();
$quote->save();
$this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->collectTotals()->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

It wont work only for the grand total, Magento and all ecommerce platforms has a lot of moving parts regarding the grand total.

I would suggest you to go with [price adjustment](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/price-adjustments/).

There are a lot of files you have to create but its easy. Just follow the documentation.

To make the adjustment dynamic , you need to change the **1.79** to something you need which will come from some sort of calculation. The dynamic data you can get it from [window.checkoutConfig](https://webkul.com/blog/adding-additional-variables-in-window-checkoutconfig-on-magento-2-checkout-page/) .

`\VENDOR\MODULE\Pricing\Adjustment::ADJUSTMENT_VALUE`

```
  /**
         * @return {Number}
         */
        getPureValue: function () {
            var price = 0;
            for (var i=0; i < window.checkoutConfig.quoteItemData.length; i++) {
              price += window.checkoutConfig.quoteItemData[i].qty * 1.79;
            }

            return price;
        },
```

After that you have to change where `\VENDOR\MODULE\Pricing\Adjustment::ADJUSTMENT_VALUE` is called, to something dynamic you want to calculate.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply .i will try

Comment: it working fiine.But how to choose adjusment price option for manually into checkout page.like when customer choose adjustment price after update quote total customer can uncheck remove adjustment price in quote total.please kindly let know this solution.

Comment: You need to add logic to specific files which are responsible for the calculation and for display of the adjustment.

Comment: sorry Vyacheslav Shaml,how to write logical code which location path and file type .now update quote total by using knockout js file.please kindly let me know guidence or reference link.

Comment: I updated my answer, give it a try.